# How do I install oracle jdk 7 on ubuntu server 12.04?

Tags: installation, server, jdk

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I install Sun/Oracle’s proprietary Java 6/7 JRE or JDK?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/56104/how-can-i-install-sun-oracles-proprietary-java-6-7-jre-or-jdk)

Folks,

I'm new in ubuntu server. As I understand it, Oracle retired the Operating System Distributor's License for Java, meaning that Canonical could no longer include the JDK or JRE in their APT repositories. This means no more "sudo apt-get install sun-java-whatever".

I just following this [tutorial](http://chrisagocs.blogspot.com/2012/06/installing-sun-jdk-160-on-ubuntu-1204.html) and other [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55848/how-do-i-install-oracle-java-jdk-7) but i still can't installing the jdk.
How do I install oracle jdk 7 on ubuntu server 12.04?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most popular way NOW is: https://github.com/flexiondotorg/oab-java6 NOTE: build .deb from OTN binaries and set up a local repository, install from there.

You can run `update-alternatives --config java` and see installed JDK/JRE and configure.

I personally prefer to use the tar.gz packages and write scripts to automate the install/config/update;-)