# Why can't I install the Java JDK

Tags: java

I ran the script here: https://github.com/flexiondotorg/oab-java6/blob/master/oab-java.sh and it succeed. But why do I get:

```
ryan@palms ~ $ /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/bin/java -version
java version "1.7.0_07"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea7 2.3.2) (7u7-2.3.2a-1ubuntu1)
OpenJDK Server VM (build 23.2-b09, mixed mode)
```

Comment: Have you run `sudo update-alternatives --config java`?

Comment: Also look into http://askubuntu.com/questions/225250/how-do-i-install-oracle-jdk-7-on-ubuntu-server-12-04/225262 and http://askubuntu.com/questions/56104/how-can-i-install-sun-oracles-proprietary-java-6-7-jre-or-jdk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must change your default java.

- `sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/java" "java" "/full/path/to/bin/java" 1`
- `sudo update-alternatives --config java`

More details [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55848/how-do-i-install-oracle-java-jdk-7).