# Installing Java on Ubuntu 64 bit

Tags: java

I have ubuntu 12.04 LTS version 64 bit . what is the procedure for installing and running Java for development purpose. I am new to Linux and Unix platform. Thanks in advance

Comment: possibly duplicated http://askubuntu.com/questions/55848/how-do-i-install-oracle-java-jdk-7

Comment: Possible duplicate : http://askubuntu.com/questions/55848/how-do-i-install-oracle-java-jdk-7

Comment: Linux is not necessarily UNIX.

Answer (score 2):

On the command line, type:

> `$ sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jre`

OR

1) Goto http://www.java.com/en/download/linux_manual.jsp
2) Download the 64-bit package.

**Installation:**

Change to the directory in which you want to install. Type:

> `cd <directory path name>`

For example, to install the software in the `/usr/java/` directory, Type:

> `cd /usr/java/`

Note about root access: To install Java in a system-wide location such as `/usr/local`, you must login as the root user to gain the necessary permissions. If you do not have root access, install Java in your home directory or a subdirectory for which you have write permissions.
Move the `.tar.gz` archive binary to the current directory.

Unpack the tarball and install Java:

> `tar zxvf jre-7u7-linux-x64.tar.gz`

The Java files are installed in a directory called `jre1.7.0_07` in the current directory. In this example, it is installed in the `/usr/java/jre1.7.0_07` directory. When the installation has completed, you will see the word Done.
Delete the `.tar.gz` file if you want to save disk space.

Comment: thanks and how do I specify the path and class-path ?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/paths.html will help. Scroll down to "Linux" section.

Comment: IMO, you are better off with the Oracle JDK rather than OpenJDK as when I used OpenJDK, I could not launch for example AndroidStudio as it checks if your using it and warns you not to.  Minecraft game also recommends not to use it as it isn't supported.  Most things will work fine with it but some apps check for it and block you even trying.

Comment: " When the installation has completed, you will see the word Done. " - umm, what? No. There is no "installation" done, only unpacking. Java isn't installed after this..

Answer (score 0):

If you are connected to internet then just click on the "Ubuntu Software Center" and type Java in the search box, you will find Java IDE's in result. choose one that you were looking and select Install.

Answer (score 0):

For me it's much easier to install it from software center, just go to development category java already there, Click to read more information i recommend you, if you need special kind of java, because ubuntu offers an Open JDK

Comment: Not if it's CLI it's not (which is the case here).

Answer (score -1):

If you have internet connected then
just do-

```
sudo apt-get install default-jdk
```

That will do the work for you...

Comment: yes ,it works everytime..the latest stable java release is installed..you dont have to worry about version number..its better...@UserName22

Comment: This doesn't install the 64-bit version which was the issue the OP had.