# PATH variable is reseting itself

Tags: 12.04, command-line, elementary

Every time I close my terminal and reopen it, simples command(e.g. ls) doesn't work. It shows the following error,

```
irfan@irfan-Y500-Elementery:~$ ls
Command 'ls' is available in '/bin/ls'
The command could not be located because '/bin' is not included in the PATH environment variable.
ls: command not found
```

I have to execute the following command `export PATH=/usr/bin:/bin` every time to correct this error,

```
irfan@irfan-Y500-Elementery:~$ export PATH=/usr/bin:/bin
irfan@irfan-Y500-Elementery:~$ ls
Assets   Documents        Example.java     Music       Public     Videos
Blender  Downloads        export           output.pdf  sudo
Desktop  Elementary Luna  jmonkeyplatform  Pictures    Templates
```

My questions is, why I have to do it every time? and what do I have to do to solve the repetition.

My /etc/environment files contains the following,

```
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games"
CLUTTER_PAINT=disable-clipped-redraws:disable-culling
```

Note : I am using ElementaryOS(based on Ubuntu 12.04)

#### Edit 1:

`echo $PATH` returns `/usr/local/jre1.7.0_51/bin:`

I followed this [answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/234594/installing-java-on-ubuntu-64-bit) to set java path.

I added

```
PATH=/usr/local/jre1.7.0_51/bin:
export PATH
```

to my /home/irfan/.bashrc file. I guess this caused the problem

Comment: If you don't run `export PATH...`, what is the result when you run `echo $PATH`? Also, try running `echo 'PATH DEFAULT=${PATH}:/usr/bin' >> .pam_environment` and rebooting.

Comment: @Wilf I tried running `echo 'PA..` and rebooting. But, echo $PATH shows only jdk on my path.

Comment: Close-voters: This question says it's about ElementaryOS rather than Ubuntu so ordinarily it would be closed. But it already has a good answer that doesn't appear Elementary-specific at all and would help Ubuntu users too. In effect I think this question turned out, by the skin of its teeth, to be effectively on topic, and we shouldn't close it. As an separate reason, especially considering the current emphasis on deleting closed questions, this question will likely be deleted if it's closed, which would harm Ubuntu users who'd benefit from the answer. I recommend against closing this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With your problem with the `.bashrc` file, your method of specifying this only:

```
PATH=/usr/local/jre1.7.0_51/bin:
export PATH
```

likely overwrote the original `$PATH` - including those already specified. so, to add `/usr/local/jre1.7.0_51/bin` as a path, in a similar manner to my suggestion above:

```
echo 'PATH DEFAULT=${PATH}:/usr/local/jre1.7.0_51/bin' >> ~/.pam_environment
```

This should add it as a path without overwriting the others in `$PATH`. It should work if you reboot/logout & login/something like that - you will see it in `echo $PATH` if it works.

Comment: I removed my jdk edit on PATH variable, and tried your command. But it shows me the following errtor, `bash: .pam_environment: Permission denied`.

Comment: With the original command, you had to make sure the terminal wass in the home directory. see edit.

Comment: It worked thanks. Don't know why, the system needed a reboot. echo $PATH shows `/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/jre1.7.0_51/bin::/usr/local/jre1.7.0_51/bin:/usr/local/jre1.7.0_51/bin`

Comment: One more question, what command should I used to append something to my PATH variable?

Comment: In `.bashrc` or `.profile`, it is as simple as `PATH="$PATH:/my/new/dir"` (no spaces around the `=`!)

Comment: Dunno why you need a reboot/whatever, just it does not always pick up the changes. To add something to `$PATH`, add it to `.pam_environment` similar to the method described above, or use @Rmano's method.

Comment: See also https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables

Comment: @Wilf If I use the command again, it replaces everything on pam_environment file.

Comment: The best place to put environment variables is (at least on ubuntu) on `.profile`, because the file is sourced by lightdm before starting your session (other distros may differ). You need a login/logout before seeing the changes, a reboot is overkill. `.pam_environment` may be ok, but is overwritten if you change language configuration/support. And @iamcreasy, if you want to add something to a file, use `>>` instead of `>` in the redirection.

Comment: @iancreasy - sorry - one `>` overwrites, two `>>` adds to it - added edit.