# How to install Java Plugin for chrome

Tags: java, google-chrome, plugins

I followed the instructions in the accepted answer to [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55848/how-do-i-install-oracle-java-jdk-7) question and was able to correctly install the latest version of Java 7.

However I do not have mozilla firefox installed but chrome.  I was therefore wondering what should be the isntructions to execute instead of:

```
mkdir ~/.mozilla/plugins
ln -s /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0/jre/lib/amd64/libnpjp2.so ~/.mozilla/plugins/
sudo /etc/init.d/apparmor restart
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out to execute the following instructions and after restarting chrome everything worked perfectly:

```
mkdir /opt/google/chrome/plugins
cd /opt/google/chrome/plugins
ln -s /usr/local/jre1.7.0/.../libnpjp2.so .
```