# Setup and install IntelliJ with JDK

Tags: software-installation, java, openjdk, jdk, oracle

Is there any scripts for downloading and installing IntelliJ with JavaJDK or OpenJDK?

I don't know how I did it before using Ubuntu 12.10 but I'm now on a fresh 13.04 install and I have been looking around for an all in one script, or some scripts I can cobble together

I have the two links detailed that I think will be handy, can anyone else add to this please?

[How do I install Oracle Java JDK 7?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55848/how-do-i-install-oracle-java-jdk-7)

[Install Oracle Java 7 in Ubuntu via PPA Repository](http://www.webupd8.org/2012/01/install-oracle-java-jdk-7-in-ubuntu-via.html)

**Update:** I have now found you can install IntelliJ through the Ubuntu software centre, so although this was a nice learning exercise for me it's not really relevant any more. Thanks to everyone that contributed.

Comment: Why do you want a script for that? It's not too complicated to do it manually. Just follow the instrucation from the links you posted and download and unzip IntelliJ. Shouldn't take you more than five minutes (plus download time).

Comment: I want a script so I can save myself five minutes ;) and also learn something in the process

Comment: If you want to learn something write the script yourself ;-) I doubt that there is a something like this out there as it is very specific.

Comment: Are there any examples? I knew this would happen, go to ask a perfectly legitimate question and get flamed in the comments

Comment: My intention wasn't to flame you. Sorry if that came out wrong.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

This should get you started:

```
#!/bin/sh

add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java &&
apt-get update &&
apt-get install oracle-java7-installer &&
echo oracle-java7-installer shared/accepted-oracle-license-v1-1 select true | sudo /usr/bin/debconf-set-selections &&
update-java-alternatives -s java-7-oracle &&

wget -O /tmp/intellij.tar.gz http://download.jetbrains.com/idea/ideaIC-12.0.4.tar.gz &&
tar xfz /tmp/intellij.tar.gz &&
cd idea-IC-123.169/bin &&
./idea.sh
```

Some things you should consider:

- I'm not sure at which part the `echo oracle-java7-installer shared/accepted-oracle-license-v1-1 select true | sudo /usr/bin/debconf-set-selections` has to be. Might be a line earlier.
- The line `cd idea-IC-123.169/bin` is dependend on the IntelliJ version, as the extracted folder is named in that way. It only works with the version available while I'm writing this.
- Same goes for the download link. It might change with a newer version.
- I'm not sure what happens if you try to add a ppa that already exists again. This could lead to problems.
- You have to execute the script as root

Comment: Excellent thanks, so `wget -O ` is that what you can use to download any file from a url?

Comment: Yes, the `-O` option specifies the output file. If you omitt it, the file is saved in the current directory with the name as it is downloaded.

Comment: See http://askubuntu.com/a/659689/438156 for an automatic way using Ubuntu Make. (that keeps the idea package updated etc)

Comment: worth mentioning you can use a regex when cd into the extracted folder:

cd idea*/bin should work

Answer (score 78):

**Installing JDK**

To install JDK, you can refer to [help.ubuntu.com/community/Java](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Java).

If you want to install openJDK,

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jdk
```

If you want to install Oracle JDK, you can use [PPA from webup8 team](http://www.webupd8.org/2012/01/install-oracle-java-jdk-7-in-ubuntu-via.html).

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install oracle-java7-installer
```

**Installing IntelliJ IDEA**

**[Updated Answer]**

Download IntelliJ IDEA CE from [www.jetbrains.com/idea/download/](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download/).

1. Extract ideaIC-XX.Y.Z.tar.gz using

   ```
   tar -zxvf ideaIC-XX.Y.Z.tar.gz
   ```
2. Run `idea.sh` in `bin` directory inside the extracted folder.
3. To create command-line runner, `Tools > Create Command-line Launcher`
4. To create a desktop entry, `Tools > Create Desktop Entry`

That's it. Now, you can launch IntelliJ from Ubuntu dash.

**[Old Answer]**

Download IntelliJ IDEA CE from [www.jetbrains.com/idea/download/](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download/).

1. Extract ideaIC-XX.Y.Z.tar.gz using

   ```
   tar -zxvf ideaIC-XX.Y.Z.tar.gz
   ```
2. Become root.

   ```
   sudo -i
   ```
3. Move the extracted folder to `/opt/idea`

   ```
   mv ideaIC-XX.Y.Z /opt/idea
   ```
4. Create a desktop file and install it:

   ```
   gedit idea.desktop
   ```

   and copy the following to the `idea.desktop` file.

   ```
   [Desktop Entry]
   Name=IntelliJ IDEA 
   Type=Application
   Exec=idea.sh
   Terminal=false
   Icon=idea
   Comment=Integrated Development Environment
   NoDisplay=false
   Categories=Development;IDE;
   Name[en]=IntelliJ IDEA
   ```

   then execute the following command to automatically install it in the unity:

   ```
   desktop-file-install idea.desktop
   ```
5. Create a symlink in `/usr/local/bin` using

   ```
   cd /usr/local/bin
   ln -s /opt/idea/bin/idea.sh
   ```
6. For idea icon to be displayed in dash, idea icon can be added as

   ```
   cp /opt/idea/bin/idea.png /usr/share/pixmaps/idea.png
   ```

That's it. Now, you can launch IntelliJ from Ubuntu dash.

Comment: thank you. Of all the guides out there, this one worked the best for me.

Comment: Exactly. This answer gives the best usable result! Kudos! :)

Comment: You can skip step four and do it at the end once intellij is running by going to Tools > Create Desktop Entry. Much easier.

Comment: @mlissner Thanks. I updated my answer finally.

Comment: Steps 1-3 can be replaced with Ubuntu make (which should update automatically, etc). See http://askubuntu.com/a/659689/438156

Answer (score 17):

New way: you can use [Ubuntu Make](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-make). To install on 16.04 (Xenial) [and later]

```
sudo apt install ubuntu-make
```

If your Ubuntu version if before 16.04 (codename Xenial), you can install from the Ubuntu Make PPA. First, add the PPA to your system:

> ```
> sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-desktop/ubuntu-make  
> sudo apt-get update
> ```

Then, installing Ubuntu Make:

> ```
> sudo apt-get install ubuntu-make
> ```

After installing Ubuntu Make, do a

```
umake ide idea
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also try my ubuntu repository: https://launchpad.net/~mmk2410/+archive/ubuntu/intellij-idea-community

To use it just run the following commands:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:mmk2410/intellij-idea-community
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install intellij-idea-community
```

Answer (score 1):

I kept installing various JB tools on a bunch of machines, so finally wrote a tiny tool to help with that, check it out here: https://github.com/MarcinZukowski/jetbrains-installer

It's also useful when JetBrains releases a new version requiring manual download, allows automating that.

Answer (score 0):

**Installing JDK**

*Oracle JDK*

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java`
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install oracle-java7-installer
```

*OpenJDK*

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-jdk
```

> You can also install openjdk 9, 10 or 11 this is as per your choice; just replace 8 with version number to install another version.

**Installing Intellij**

*Installing intellij from [snap store](https://snapcraft.io/store)*

```
sudo snap install intellij-idea-ultimate --classic --edge
```

> This is a ulimate edition so you need activation code in order to activate it.

```
sudo snap install intellij-idea-community --classic
```

> This is community version so don't need activation code; but it has limited features and tools.

Happy Coding :)