# why i can't find intellij IDEA in software center?

Tags: software-center, intellij

i can see the program existing when i go to software center via the browser, but its not in the actual program! even hitting the download link in the applications' page in browser, couldn't direct me to it in software center!
is there any other ways to install it? I'm new to Linux!

Comment: Welcome to AU! Can you please provide some more detail? What version of *Ubuntu are you on? Also it seems that you actually want to know how to install IDEA, so you should just ask that. Installing it through the software center is just one way to do it.

Answer (score 2):

In Ubuntu 12.04 and Ubuntu 14.04 open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt-get install intellij-idea-ce
```

The installation process of IntelliJ IDEA 13 Community Edition is pretty straightforward; you don't even have to give the software provider your email address.

Comment: I did not find this in 15.04. Answer to similar problem at http://askubuntu.com/a/659689/438156

Answer (score 0):

No. Software center displays only application installed via dpkg or apt-get

If you installed from download page using tar.gz or similar package, it won't show in software center.

Depending what file type you downloaded, there are different ways to install it.