# GNOME adding desktop for GNOME menu not parsed

Tags: unity, gnome, .desktop

Good day all

Following the method specified in the [GDM3 wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Desktop_entries) to add a desktop file for the GNOME menu,

I get the following error:

```
Oct  4 09:54:06 cx-W55xEU gnome-software[1741]: failed to rescan: Failed to parse /home/cx/.local/share/applications/android-studio.desktop file: cannot process file of type application/x-desktop
Oct  4 09:54:47 cx-W55xEU gnome-software[1741]: failed to rescan: Failed to parse /usr/share/applications/android-studio.desktop file: cannot process file of type application/x-desktop
```

The desktop file I am trying to create is for Android Studio.

Desktop file contents

```
[Desktop Entry]

# The type as listed above
Type=Application

# The version of the desktop entry specification to which this file complies
Version=1.0

# The name of the application
Name=Android-Studio

# A comment which can/will be used as a tooltip
Comment=Android studio IDE

# The path to the folder in which the executable is run
Path=/opt/google/android-studio/android-studio/bin/

# The executable of the application.
Exec=studio.sh

# The name of the icon that will be used to display this entry
Icon=studio.png

# Describes whether this application needs to be run in a terminal or not
Terminal=false

# Describes the categories in which this entry should be shown
Categories=Education;Languages;Java;
```

Path link specified contains:

```
# ll /opt/google/android-studio/android-studio/bin/

total 152
drwxrwxr-x 1 root root   348 Sep 15 16:17 ./
drwxrwxr-x 1 root root   160 Sep 15 16:17 ../
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   136 Sep 15 15:49 appletviewer.policy
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 23072 Sep 15 15:49 fsnotifier*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 29648 Sep 15 15:49 fsnotifier64*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 26453 Sep 15 15:49 fsnotifier-arm*
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  7482 Sep 15 15:52 idea.properties
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   278 Sep 15 15:49 inspect.sh*
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  8531 Sep 15 15:49 libbreakgen64.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  6807 Sep 15 15:49 libbreakgen.so
drwxrwxr-x 1 root root    12 Sep 15 16:17 lldb/
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  2275 Sep 15 15:49 log.xml
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   527 Sep 15 15:49 studio64.vmoptions
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  9816 Sep 15 15:49 studio.png
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  6876 Sep 15 15:49 studio.sh*
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   534 Sep 15 15:49 studio.vmoptions
```

This is a curious error as to I have never had a problem like this when adding a .desktop file

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I founnd my answer after a 'wee-bit' more Googling, surprisingly something that is not mentioned on the GDM wiki but something I came across per-chance from a [askubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/589615/creating-an-application-launcher-icon-for-android-studio) post

**Solution:**

Add `bash -i` infront of the Exec file, as shown

```
Exec=bash -i "/opt/google/android-studio/android-studio/bin/studio.sh" %f
```

**Final Solution**

```
[Desktop Entry]

# The type as listed above
Type=Application

# The version of the desktop entry specification to which this file complies
Version=1.0

# The name of the application
Name=Android-Studio

# A comment which can/will be used as a tooltip
Comment=Android studio IDE

# The executable of the application.
Exec=bash -i "/opt/google/android-studio/android-studio/bin/studio.sh" %f

# The name of the icon that will be used to display this entry
Icon=/opt/google/android-studio/android-studio/bin/studio.png

# Describes whether this application needs to be run in a terminal or not
Terminal=false

# Describes the categories in which this entry should be shown
Categories=Education;Languages;Java;

StartupNotify=true
```

Note aswel, I added a line [StartupNotify](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/desktop-entry-spec-latest.html). I found a reasonable explaination for its purpose, aswel as a few other components of a `.desktop` file

Hope this helps!

Comment: I'm glad it works, but this does not explain the `cannot process file of type application/x-desktop` error message :-\