# What is the required IntelliJ environment for Ubuntu?

Tags: java, 17.04, intellij

I asked this here in hopes that someone well-versed in both IntelliJ and Ubuntu can shed some light on this. I went through hell trying to make a Java program run on Eclipse/IntelliJ because of one thing: incorrectly configured environment.

I'm now trying to get a fairly complicated Java program to run on Ubuntu IntelliJ which I already installed fresh, so before I even bother trying to make it run (since my past sad history with IDEs means it's gonna screw with 50 over unidentifiable errors in a correct source code), I need to ask: Is there a correct environment setting for intelliJ? I have already installed OpenJDK 8 on Ubuntu 17.04.

Comment: Why not to install Oracle Java? See this: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-manually-install-oracle-java-on-a-debian-or-ubuntu-vps

Comment: You could see this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/272314/setup-and-install-intellij-with-jdk.

Comment: Can we see a link to that java program your trying to run?

Comment: I didn't do anything special to set up IntelliJ: 1) install OpenJDK 8, 2) download, extract and run the most recent IntelliJ release. How *exactly* did you install it? If those steps work but you can't set up and run you software project then your question is likely about software development and not about Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to install the following to get IntelliJ working:

- IntelliJ itself (Best way is the JetBrains toolbox, as it makes updates easier)
- A JDK (Easiest way is to install `openjdk-8-jdk` with `apt-get`, although Oracle java works just as well)

After installing these you may need to set your JDK inside IntelliJ, you should use the path `/usr/lib/jvm/openjdk-8/`