# Ubuntu Failes to Recognize Java

Tags: command-line, java, minecraft, openjdk

I've been having an issue with Java since I installed Ubuntu and it has been the main reason I have stopped playing certain Java-based games such as Minecraft. You see, although I've downloaded *OpenJDK 6* from the Software Center, Ubuntu refuses to recognize that I do in fact have it installed. When I type `java -version` into the terminal, the following pops up:

```
The program 'java' can be found in the following packages:
 * default-jre
 * gcj-4.6-jre-headless
 * gcj-4.7-jre-headless
 * openjdk-7-jre-headless
 * openjdk-6-jre-headless
Try: sudo apt-get install <selected package>
```

Giving it the benefit of the doubt, I tried installing these as well. Unfortunately, `java -version` continues to present me this same exact message every time. Also, just to make sure the terminal wasn't drunk, I checked *Minecraft.jar>Properties>Open With* and *OpenJDK 6* was, unsurprisingly, not available from the list.

Edit: Here are the results of `dpkg -l | grep jdk`:

```
ii  openjdk-6-jre:i386                        6b27-1.12.6-1ubuntu0.12.10.2              i386         OpenJDK Java runtime, using Hotspot JIT
ii  openjdk-6-jre-headless:i386               6b27-1.12.6-1ubuntu0.12.10.2              i386         OpenJDK Java runtime, using Hotspot JIT (headless)
ii  openjdk-6-jre-lib                         6b27-1.12.6-1ubuntu0.12.10.2              all          OpenJDK Java runtime (architecture independent libraries)
ii  openjdk-7-jre:i386                        7u21-2.3.9-0ubuntu0.12.10.1               i386         OpenJDK Java runtime, using Hotspot JIT
ii  openjdk-7-jre-headless:i386               7u21-2.3.9-0ubuntu0.12.10.1               i386         OpenJDK Java runtime, using Hotspot JIT (headless)
ii  openjdk-7-jre-lib                         7u21-2.3.9-0ubuntu0.12.10.1               all          OpenJDK Java runtime (architecture independent libraries)
```

Comment: Please, [edit] your question to include the output of `dpkg -l | grep jdk`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something went wrong with the installation and some links are set in a wrong way.
Try uninstalling Java:

sudo apt-get purge icedtea-* openjdk-*

Restart your computer and install it again.

Maybe you also want to try out Sun-Java instead of openJDK. Follow this thread:

[How can I install Sun/Oracle's proprietary Java JDK 6/7/8 or JRE?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/56104/how-can-i-install-sun-oracles-proprietary-java-6-7-jre-or-jdk)

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I prefer using the Oracle JDK over the default openJDK (IcedTea).    Just download the .tar or .bin  and extract it to /opt/java/JDK1.7.0_25  (or whatever).  Then, [use "update-alternatives" to add the links](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55848/how-do-i-install-oracle-java-jdk-7) (into your PATH) for that location.

Comment: I tried this as you suggested, however, Oracle JDK 7 still fails to show up on the "Open With" list just as OpenJDK 6 had. Any thoughts? Regardless, thank you for at least attempting to help.