# update-alternatives: error: no alternatives for

Tags: java, jdk

I tried to follow the excellent answer to the question [How to correctly remove OpenJDK and JRE and set the system use only and only Sun JDK and JRE?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/21131/how-to-correctly-remove-openjdk-and-jre-and-set-the-system-use-only-and-only-sun), but there seem to be some side effects:

```
root@ubuntu10:/usr/local/bin# update-java-alternatives -s java-6-sun
update-alternatives: error: no alternatives for java-rmi.cgi.
update-alternatives: error: no alternatives for mozilla-javaplugin.so.
update-alternatives: error: no alternatives for xulrunner-1.9-javaplugin.so.
update-alternatives: error: no alternatives for mozilla-javaplugin.so.
update-alternatives: error: no alternatives for xulrunner-1.9-javaplugin.so.
```

Any idea how to correct [this](http://linuxsagas.digitaleagle.net/2011/05/04/installing-sun-java-6/)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sun-6-java is being phased out by Oracle and is no longer supported. This is why there are no plugins available for your browser anymore.

OpenJDK is the only stack you should be using as sun-java-6 is outdated and deprecated.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenJDK

If you would like to use Proprietary Closed Source features in Java you will need to install the version from java.com (which is also OpenJDK so don't really see any benefit over the Ubuntu Repository version).

OpenJDK is backwards compatible with the old Sun-6-java. What can you not run with OpenJDK?

Oracle Offers Links to Java 7, you have to go out of your way to get Java 6.

The previous edit to my post by "broiyan" is depricated.

Comment: Thanks +1 for this information. I wasn't aware that OpenJSK ia the same exact code Oracle uses. Since I develop on both Windows and Linux (for Android), I wanted the Java bugs to compatible with each other... I just read the link you provided that OpenJDK is going to be the Java SE 7 reference implementation. Fortunately, there is this great `update-java-alternatives` command that allows me to switch back painlessly.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can simply add the `partner` repository in `/etc/apt/sources.list` :

```
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu lucid partner
```

If you are not on lucid, replace `lucid` with your distribution (you can get it with `lsb_release -c`).

If you still have problem with the java plugin, you can do like I did, follow [the instructions here](http://www.php-architect.com/blog/2010/10/19/installing-java-plugin-for-firefox-on-ubuntu-10-10-maverick/) :

```
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/lib/mozilla/plugins/mozilla-javaplugin.so mozilla-javaplugin.so /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun/jre/lib/amd64/libnpjp2.so 1
```

If you are not on a 64 bits system, replace `amd64` by `i386`.