# Java plugins are not detected after upgrading

Tags: java

After an upgrade to Trusty Tahr (14.04), it seems Java has ceased to work in several browsers (tested on Firefox, Chromium, and Chrome).

`ubuntu-restricted-extras` is installed, Oracle-Java was installed using the webupd8 PPA, and I also tried applying [a fix to an update-alternatives error](https://askubuntu.com/questions/79747/update-alternatives-error-no-alternatives-for), and installing IcedTea, to no avail.

How to activate Java plugins in the browsers?

Comment: Regarding Chromium, see [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/450683/java-plugin-in-chromium). Does installing OpenJDK 7 work for Firefox?

Comment: @user68186 - icedtea is installed.

Comment: @saiarcot895 - Does that mean that no Java plugin is available for chromium (or chrome) at the moment **?!** Is everyone down at Google just ignoring that humongous elephant in the room?

Comment: @EliranMalka: Java is outside of their control, and they have their reasons for deprecating NPAPI (security, permissions, etc.). As far as I know, the only way to use Java in the browser is to re-enable NPAPI (for the time being) by recompiling Chromium.

Comment: @saiarcot895 - holy s***!

Comment: I've got the same problem but recompiling Chromium is definitely not an option. It takes a horrendous amount of disk space and time.
Will probably just use Firefox for the rare sites that require Java.

Answer (score -1):

Check the symbolic link in your browser's plugin directory and make sure it's pointing to the correct installation of Java (eg /usr/local/java/jre1.x.xxx/lib/amd64/libnpjp2.so)

Comment: no reason for it to change - checked to be `libnpjp2.so -> /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre/lib/amd64/libnpjp2.so`.

Comment: I don't think this should get downvotes becuase it is what [Oracle suggests](http://www.java.com/en/download/help/enable_browser_ubuntu.xml). However I tried this too, and it did not work for me.